# C++ Undefined Behavior or Not? (again)

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I looked through a pile of the questions and couldn't see this, though I'm sure its on SO somewhere already.  So I apologize and figure this will get closed, but hopefully someone will confirm my answer first!

Am I correct in thinking that:

```
while (--len > -1 && ptr = str[len])
```

Is well defined (not undefined!) behavior?  The way I understand this is that && is a sequence point, and the way short-circuiting would work would mean that `--len > -1` should be evaluated first, making the second part not happen if it's unsafe.

I wasn't sure if I was correct in this thought process though.

Comment: Depends what the value of len is before this statement. What if it is 0 or greater. then ptr=str[len] would be evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, good point. It's not a danger in my situation, but I didn't think about it in the first place which is bad. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is defined behaviour as `&&` is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) and the way you understand it is correct. From the linked Wikipedia page:

> In C[2] and C++,[3] sequence points occur in the following places:
>
> Between evaluation of the left and right operands of the && (logical AND), || (logical OR), and comma operators. For example, in the expression *p++ != 0 && *q++ != 0, all side effects of the sub-expression *p++ != 0 are completed before any attempt to access q.

This does not, however, ensure that the `--len` will not result in an index beyond the bounds of `str`. If `str` is a null-terminated `str` you could change to:

```
while (--len > -1 && len < strlen(str) && ptr = str[len])
```

Comment: @hmjd: I would avoid recomputing `strlen` at each run of the loop, it certainly is wasteful. If `len` is inferior to `strlen(str)` to begin with then decrementing it should not change that fact. Of course, this assumes `str` itself does not move, which seems the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. The order is:

1. `len` is decremented
2. (new value of) `len` is compared to `-1`
3. If (2) evaluated to true, `ptr = str[len]`

Answer (score 0):

You are right to think that `ptr = str[len]` is not executed if `--len > -1` is false (it could be an undefined behavior is len is too big for the indexed array, I assume it isn't what you fear). `--len` could be an undefined behavior if len is INT_MIN beforehand (again not probable if len is initialized sanely) as overflow of signed arithmetic is an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (--len > -1 && ptr = str[len])
```

in example for len = 1 ( if len is int ) things goes like that:

```
1) len = len-1=0
2) ptr = str[0]
```

2) is because of decrement of len if first part of if statement.
is that what you wanted?

But behaviour is defned and first part will be checked first.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually OK. The key here is that you aren't writing to `len` more than once.

First you pre-decrement `len`. Then check if the decremented value of `len` is at least 0. Next, assign `str[len]` (using the decremented `len`) into `ptr`. Finally check if `ptr` is non-null, and if so execute the `while` loop statements.

Note that if `len` is unsigned `-1` will get promoted to unsigned and the loop will pretty much assuredly fail the first iteration. Additionally even if `len` is signed if it has the minimum int value (`std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`) decrementing that is unspecified.

Comment: *The key here is that you aren't writing to len more than once.* This is not necessarily the issue. `map[++i] = i` only writes to `i` once, and yet is undefined.